# What params are available with the_content filter?

Tags: filters, the-content

I am looking for what params are passed to my filter function. Where can I find such info in the codex?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content didn't provide much info

I wanted to know if the post is a child of another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there are any additional parameters passed, per se, to `the_content`, but global variables like **$post** are accessible.

So something like this would work:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'check_for_post_parent' );

function check_for_post_parent($content) {
     global $post;
     if ($parent_id == $post->post_parent) {
          //do what you want to $content here, 
          //now that you know $parent_id
          //...
          }
     return $content;
     }
```

Answer (score 10):

In `wp-includes/post-template.php` you’ll find the place, where the filters are applied:

```
/**
 * Display the post content.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $more_link_text Optional. Content for when there is more text.
 * @param string $stripteaser Optional. Teaser content before the more text.
 */
function the_content($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = 0) {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo $content;
}
```

The only parameter is the content text.

But you can always use the global variable $post to get more information about the currently used post. Try the following snippet in your theme’s functions.php:

```
/*
 * Priority 100 to let other filters do their work first.
 */
add_filter( 'the_content', 'debug_post_info', 100 );
/**
 * Print information about the current post.
 *
 * @param  string $content
 * @return string
 */
function debug_post_info( $content )
{
    return $content . '<hr><pre>' . var_export( $GLOBALS['post'], TRUE ) . '</pre>';
}
```

On a child page you get some nice data:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'ID' => 2168,
   'post_author' => '2',
   'post_date' => '2007-09-04 09:52:18',
   'post_date_gmt' => '2007-09-03 23:52:18',
   'post_content' => 'This page has a parent.',
   'post_title' => 'Child page 2',
   'post_excerpt' => '',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'comment_status' => 'open',
   'ping_status' => 'open',
   'post_password' => '',
   'post_name' => 'child-page-2',
   'to_ping' => '',
   'pinged' => '',
   'post_modified' => '2007-09-04 09:52:18',
   'post_modified_gmt' => '2007-09-03 23:52:18',
   'post_content_filtered' => '',
   'post_parent' => 2167,
   'guid' => 'http://wpthemetestdata.wordpress.com/parent-page/child-page-1/child-page-2/',
   'menu_order' => 0,
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_mime_type' => '',
   'comment_count' => '0',
   'ancestors' => 
  array (
    0 => 2167,
    1 => 2166,
  ),
   'filter' => 'raw',
))
```

`'post_parent' => 2167` is the ID of the parent post. On pages without a parent the parameter is set to `0`.

Comment: I get so inspired when I read your bits of info. Thanks, very very much! I had a vague understanding of this process I had just ran with, this cleared up a lot. :)