# Do all wordpress themes a similar class name for content?

Tags: posts, jquery

I was wondering if all wordpress theme have a similar class name for the content.. For example I know the class for  post/content in the twenty ten and twenty eleven is

```
.entry-content
```

if not then how would I go about referring contents for all theme using jQuery?

e.g $j('.entry-content').css('color','red');

thanks

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be: *what are you trying to do, that you need to target all post content*? If your ultimate goal is to **change the foreground color of all post content to red**,you should edit your question to ask *that* question instead. Using jQuery is but one of many **implementations** to solve a given problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mandatory class name for posts. Many themes use the [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) if that is needed but you cannot rely on it.

To change the output of [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) add a [filter to `'the_content'`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12687/73).

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an attempt at marking up web content in [hAtom](http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom) or [hNews](http://microformats.org/wiki/hnews) (an extension of hAtom). The `entry-content` class doesn't get assigned to the whole post but only to the body text, without title (which is `entry-title`). So it isn't really a replacement for `the_post_class()` because that gets assigned to the whole post. But for `entry-content` to make sense, the article needs a class of `hentry`. So using `the_post_class()`, it would be `the_post_class('hentry')` to include this class in the output.

And it has a very practical use: this markup has been established as kind of a standard for all those web services crawling and reformatting content, like Instapaper, Readability, Pocket etc. All those services use hAtom markup to identify the correct portions of an article. See Readability's [Article Publishing Guidelines](https://www.readability.com/publishers/guidelines) for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't tell.

If you're writing a plugin I'd say the safe way to go is to create an options page where the user can set the classname to use, and if none is set, use `.entry-content`